# Why does it shows same logs twice (one as info and one as error with same message) on stackdriver?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, google-bigquery, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am preparing some logging using python, but whenever I run my code it generates the logs but shows twice on stackdriver console (one as info and one as error). Anyone have idea on how to deal with this problem.

my code:

```
import logging
from google.cloud import logging as gcp_logging


log_client = gcp_logging.Client()
log_client.setup_logging()

# here executing some bigquery operations
logging.info("Query result loaded into temporary table: {}".format(temporary_table))

# here executing some bigquery operations
logging.error("Query executed with empty result set.")
```

When I run above code it show above logs twice on stackdriver.

Info:2019-10-17T11:54:02.504Z cf-mycloudfunctionname Query result loaded into temporary table: mytable

Error:2019-10-17T11:54:02.505Z cf-mycloudfunctionname Query result loaded into temporary table: mytable

Comment: And ""Query executed with empty result set." never appeared in log?

Comment: I'm thinking there has to be more code than this (eg. temporary_table is not defined).  How is this code being invoked?  Is it perhaps a Cloud Function and the function is failing after the first logging statement and being retried (which would result in a second run and hence a second log?).  Is the invocation REST, GCS trigger, PubSub or something else?

Comment: @YunZhang It appears only if the query result is empty (I have put "# here executing some bigquery operations")

Comment: @Kolban I am running this code from cloud function.

Answer (score 0):

What I can see is that both (error & info) has been recognized as a plane text, so it sent the same message as info for stderr and stdout, this is why you are getting two same messages.

What you need to do is to correct phrase the this two logs into an [structured JSON](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging), this to be recognized by stackdriver as one entity with the correct payload to be displayed.

Additional, you can configure the  stackdriver agent to send the logs as you need to be sent, take a look to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration).

Also It will depend from where you are trying to retrieve this logs GCE, GKE, BQ. In some cases its preferible to change the structure of fluentd directly instead of the stackdriver agent.